# SwiftUI DatePicker should be editable inline

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, swiftui

I'm using a `DatePicker`inside a SwiftUI `List`. I'm only interested in hours and minutes and therefore don't need the newly introduced calendar view.

How can I prevent the popup that appears once a user taps on the time (8:30 AM)? It would be ideal if it can be edited inline like in the iOS calendar app.

[image]
[image]

Here's how I'm creating the `DatePicker`:

```
DatePicker("Send motivation at", selection: $settings.dailyMotivationReminder, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .datePickerStyle(DefaultDatePickerStyle())
                .font(.system(.body, design: .serif))
                .disabled(!settings.isDailyMotivationEnabled)
                .opacity(settings.isDailyMotivationEnabled ? 1.0 : 0.4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GraphicalDatePickerStyle`:

```
List {
    HStack {
        Text("Send motivation at")
        DatePicker("", selection: $settings.dailyMotivationReminder, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
            .font(.system(.body, design: .serif))
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that. I’ve actually set that style and it did not change anything. I assume your code is working fine, so it might be something else that is causing the picker to show in a pop up.

Comment: tested @pawello2222 code, all work as expected (mac 11, ios 14.2). So yes, it must be something else causing the problem. Show us the other code you are using, so we can track down the issue.

Comment: Hey guys, you were right. The real issue was that I had to put it in a ``HStack`` and split up ``Text``and ``DatePicker``otherwise it would not work. Many thanks!